SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input when parsing API data
I am trying to develop an browser extension, after calling my weather API when I try to parse the JSON data, it raise error in console like:

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (at script.js:36:30) at HTMLButtonElement.fetchData (script.js:36:30)


I need to parse the promise object from the weather API to show the weather information in my browser extension
function developContainer(data) {
    let con = document.getElementById('info-container');
    con.innerHTML = '';
    let newPc = document.createElement("p");
    let newPf = document.createElement("p");
    newPc.innerHTML = "C&deg;/" + data.temp_c;
    newPf.innerHTML = "F&deg;/" + data.temp_f;
    con.appendChild(newPc);
    con.appendChild(newPf);
}

async function fun() {
    let input = document.getElementById('input');
    input.value = 'loading...';
    let res = await fetch('https://ipapi.co/json/', {method: "GET"});
    let json =await res.json();
    city = json.city;
    input.value = city;
    console.log(city);    
}

async function fetchData() {
    // if(city === '') return;
    let inputEle = document.getElementById("input");
    let location = inputEle.value;
    console.log(location);
    let url = `https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=7afae986719f43e0b91135851240406&q=${location}`
    if(location === '') return;
    try{
        // let res = await fetch(
        //     `https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=7afae986719f43e0b91135851240406&q=${location}`,
        //     {
        //         mode: "no-cors",
        //         method: "GET"
        //     }
        // );
        let res = await fetch(url, {method: "GET", mode: "no-cors"});
        let json = await res.json();
        console.log(json);
        let data = json.current;
        developContainer(data);

        console.log(json.current.temp_c);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', fetchData, false);
}, false)

fun();



The error probably means that the fetch is returning an error page instead of JSON content. You can use your browser "Network" developer tab to research the issue.

mode: "no-cors" is an issue: it won't magically make things work - what it does is tell the browser you're not interested in the data for this request. It bypasses CORS because you've specified no cross origin data would be used. Therefore the browser would oblige and do the request then hide the response data from you. Again, that's what you've said with "no-cors" - that you're not going to use the data. Yet you do try to use it await res.json();. If you want to consume Weather API data - figure out how to do that. Don't break your code then ask how to unbreak it.

Please reset your weather API key as soon as possible, and consider not sharing them in future?

Weather API request cors error

https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/for-those-of-you-who-are-stuck-on-the-weather-api-projects/135516
